# Using a PHP array inside of a PHP function?

Tags: php, arrays, string, function

I am trying to figure out how I can use a PHP array inside of a PHP function. I was able to use string replace to replace {count} with the $counter variable inside of the function. But I am unable to do the same thing to a array that is inside the string. I tried using `$i` from the For loop to select the arrays index, but that did not work. I also tried using `{count}` for the array index and then used string replace to replace it with the `$counter` variable. That did not work also. If anyone can point in the right direction, I would apperciate it. Thank you for your time.

```
<?php
    function repeatHTML($repeatCount, $repeatString){
        $counter = 1;
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $repeatCount; $i++) {
            $replacedRepeatString = str_replace('{count}', $counter, $repeatString);
            echo $replacedRepeatString;
            $counter++;
        }   
    }

    $titleContent = array('orange', 'apple', 'grape', 'watermelon');

    repeatHTML(4, '<div class="image-{count}">'.$titleContent[$i].'</div>'); 
?>
```

**Output Example:**

```
<div class="image-1">orange</div>
<div class="image-2">apple</div>
<div class="image-3">grape</div>
<div class="image-4">watermelon</div>
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want, could you please post what you'd like the output of your example to be?

Comment: I added output example. Sorry updated it again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why would you need this, but you can do something like this:

```
function repeatHTML( $repeatHTML, $repeatArray ) {
    foreach ( $repeatArray as $key => $repeatValue ) {
        $replacedRepeatString = str_replace('{count}', $key, $repeatHTML);
        $replacedRepeatString = str_replace('{value}', $repeatValue, $repeatHTML);
        echo $replacedRepeatString;
    }
}

// 1 => only if you want to start from 1, instead of 0
$titleContent = array( 1 => 'orange', 'apple', 'grape', 'watermelon' );

repeatHTML( '<div class="image-{count}">{value}</div>', $titleContent );
```

If you want to use an array in a function, you have to set it as a separate attribute.

Now you don't need to use the `$repeatCount` attribute, if you want to go through te entire array.

**EDIT:**

You can also make your own "template" by combining HTML and PHP.

```
<?php
$content = array( 1 => 'orange', 'apple', 'grape', 'watermelon' );

foreach ( $content as $key => $value )
{
    ?> <div class="image-<?=$key?>"><?=$value?></div> <?php
}
```

I would recommend using an existing template engine, though. This code is not as clear and it could become really messy.

Comment: What if I did not want to include the array inside of the function, because there could be any number of arrays being used within the string. And I want to do this, cause I repeat so much HTML code, this would save a lot of time.

Comment: You can use any array you'd like in this funciton. Better solution yet to repetitive HTML code would be a template engine. For example [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) or [Latte](https://github.com/nette/latte) come to mind.

Comment: Checking them out, thanks. I still wanna figure this out tho, it would come in handy right now. Sometimes I build simple information websites and it is just a pain to have to repeat so much code.

Comment: I edited my answer. You can use PHP + HTML combination. Wouldn't recommend it, though, it is better to use Twig template. It's almost as though you're having HTML with PHP functions.

Comment: Ya I had it working like that too. My thing was just trying to not have to put the array in the function, so then I could have as many arrays I wanted in that string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having more problems in your code. You do not need to replace anything. You can define and call your function like this:

```
function repeatHTML($arr){ // add array as parameter
   $content = ""; // initialize variable
   $i = 0; // initialize variable
   foreach($arr as $k=>$n){ // loop through array
     $content .= '<div class="image-'.$i.'">'.$n.'</div>'; // fill variable with html
     $i++; // increment counter variable
   }
   return $content;
}

$titleContent = array(0=>'orange', 1=>'apple', 2=>'grape', 3=>'watermelon'); // fill array
echo repeatHTML($titleContent); // call function
```

Comment: I do not think I explain myself well enough. I want to be able to put in the string (the string is the HTML code that needs to be repeated). I want to be able to put in a string, that can contain arrays, and where the index of the array is counted up, based upon the for loop.

Comment: I used to do that serveral years ago. I think it is a bad pratice. You'll end up in big mixture of html and php. Separe view from logic!

Comment: Understood. Probably why the other guy suggested a template engine. Thanks for your input, I still wanna figure this out tho!

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned it up a bit and wrote a general function to help you with arrays. Please note that I agree this may not necessarily be the best option - but it does solve your problem the way you wanted it to.

```
function repeatHTML($count, $string, $array){
    foreach ($array as $index => $value) {
        echo str_replace(['{count}', '{value}'], [$index + 1, $value], $string);
    }
}

$titleContent = array('orange', 'apple', 'grape', 'watermelon');
repeatHTML(4, '<div class="image-{count}">{value}</div>', $titleContent);
```

This outputs `<div class="image-1">orange</div><div class="image-2">apple</div><div class="image-3">grape</div><div class="image-4">watermelon</div>`, you could easily add e.g. a newline or a `<br>` in the echo statement if you need a blank line.

If you need any help explaining how the function works, please let me know.

Comment: Anyway to make it so I do not have to include the array inside of the function? I could have many arrays for something I want to repeat.

Comment: You mean like if you have `array('orange', 'apple', array('grape', 'watermelon'))` etc? Or do you mean that you don't always send an array?

Comment: What if I had something like this: <div class="image-{count}">{value}<span>{value-2}</span></div> See how there could be many values? That is why if I put the array in the function, then I am limited to one array. How can I support many different arrays?

Comment: If you want to send a dynamic number of arrays to the function, that's likely going to become a serious headache. I am sorry, but I don't think I'll be able to provide a good solution for you. I hope you'll find a good answer though - good luck!

Comment: All good. I was able to come up with your solution,  I just did not know how to do the dynamic array part. Guess I will keep searching, thanks for your help.